# How to change the value of an specific associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've a dynamically generated very huge array called `$test_package_data`. For your understanding I'm giving below the contents of array `$test_package_data`.

Now what I want to achieve is convert the value of an array key

```
$test_duration = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($some_key['test_duration']);
```

In short I want to update the value of a key `['test_duration']` eveywhere in the array. But not understanding how should I loop over the array and achieve the desired result.

Comment: If you generate this array, couldn't it be better to put value in format you need while generation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) and adjust a value if the key matches `'test_duration'`:

```
array_walk_recursive($test_package_data, function(&$value, $key) {
    if ($key == 'test_duration') {
        $value = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over `$test_package_data['category_detail'][0]['test_detail']`. So code will be something like,

```
foreach($test_package_data['category_detail'][0]['test_detail'] as $key => $value){
    $test_package_data['category_detail'][0]['test_detail'][$key]['test_duration'] = 
    ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value['test_duration']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `array_walk_recursive` is the best, but this should also work.

```
function changValue($dataArray) {
  foreach($dataArray as $key=>$val) {
   if(is_array($val)) {
     return changValue($val);
   } else {
     if ($key == 'test_duration') {
        $value = ConvertTimeStampToTimeFormate($value);
    }
   }
  }
}

changeValue($yourArray);
```

Comment: Did you even test this?