# Update a value of a specific key of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to update a value of a specific key of an associative array with a form.

This is how my form looks:

```
<form class="wpd_edit_note_322" method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" id="list_note" name="list_note" value="ba222f06db">
<p><textarea id="plugn_note" name="plugin_note" placeholder="Note(Optional)" ></textarea></p>
<p><input class="list_note_id" name="plugin_note_id" type="hidden" value="322"></p>
<p><input class="list_edit_button" type="submit" value="Save"></p>

</form>
```

and this is how I am trying to update the value of key `322` on submit:

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['list_note'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['list_note'],'edit_item_note') )
    { 


        $add_to_ID = $_POST['plugin_note_id'];
        $note = $_POST['plugin_note'];


        $existing_list = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [320] => This is the plugin that I am using on my site. ) 
    [1] => Array ( [322] => My Microblog poster bla blah bla. ) 
    [2] => Array ( [318] => ) 
    );
foreach ( $existing_list as $k => $v ) {
      $existing_list[$k][$add_to_ID] = $note;
        } 
}
```

I see the $_POST values when I echo it out. so I guess the form is working but the foreach loop is not working properly.

I also tried to use `array_walk_recursive()` instead of the foreach loop, mentioned here with no avail:
[How to change the value of an specific associative array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455644/how-to-change-the-value-of-an-specific-associative-array-in-php)

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Your array syntax for `$existing_list` is incorrect. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Need commas after each row in your $existing_list array

Comment: the array list actually is a `print_r` version of `get_post_meta($postid, 'my_list_items', TRUE )` I just added the print version to show the array. should I use the `var_dump` output? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually adds the array($add_to_ID => $note) to every element of the $existing_list array, but it changes the one with the index 322. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($existing_list as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value[$add_to_ID])) {
        $existing_list[$key][$add_to_ID] = $note;
        break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($existing_list)`? Place this after the foreach but not outside the `if ( isset( $_POST['list_note'] ) ...' block.

Comment: I dont get anything if i add the code inside the `if` but if I add the code inside the `foreach` loop. I get this: `array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [320]=> string(46) "This is the plugin that I am using on my site." } [1]=> array(1) { [322]=> string(59) "My Microblog poster  blah bla bla" } [2]=> array(1) { [318]=> string(0) "" } }`  Thanks.

Comment: Did you put the var_dump inside the if block which is inside the foreach? If yes it means the condition is never true. Dump the value of $add_to_ID and $note. What is the output?

Comment: I added `var_dump($add_to_ID); var_dump($note);` after the `break;` and did not get any output. but when I add the code after `break; }` I get form submit value as output.

Comment: After the `break` it won't work. But it seems the isset condition is never true so I suggest check all the values (array, array keys, post data) again. The code seems to be okay, there is something wrong with the values.